# Change image in MainWindow from class

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to change place of display image in my `MainWindow`, so in it I have:

```
<Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
    <Image Name="BartenderX1X1Image" Source="/Images/KelnerZTaca.gif" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100"/>
    <Image Name="BartenderX1X2Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100"/>
</Grid>
```

And I have created class control, with method:

```
public void BartenderMooveRight()
{
    foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        if (window.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow))
        {
            (window as MainWindow).BartenderX1X1Image.Source = null;
            (window as MainWindow).BartenderX1X2Image.Source = bartenderImage.Source;
        }
    }
}
```

When I call it from my `MainWindow` nothing is happening. Why does the image from `BartenderX1X1Image` not disappear and the one from `BartenderX1X2Image.Source` not appear?

Comment: Why do you use two image components if only one will ever display an image? Can’t you just switch the source on a single element?

Comment: It's only example to check if it works.

Comment: The height of your Grid is only 58 and both images height individually is 58 one will be off bottom of grid and thus hidden from view. increase height of grid or consider using a different layout container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which panel had you placed the two Images, if its inside a  Panel chances are they overlay on each other.  Try using StackPanel.
Like this,

```
<StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58"
            Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
   <Image Name="BartenderX1X1Image" Source="/Images/KelnerZTaca.gif" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Width="100"/>
   <Image Name="BartenderX1X2Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: `<Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
            <Image Name="BartenderX1X1Image" Source="/Images/KelnerZTaca.gif" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100"/>
            <Image Name="BartenderX1X2Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100"/>
        </Grid>` It's inside the grid

Comment: try this,
<StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Height="58" 
Margin="2,0,0,0" 
Grid.Row="1" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="100">            
 <Image Name="BartenderX1X1Image" Source="/Images/KelnerZTaca.gif" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100"/>           
 <Image Name="BartenderX1X2Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100"/>        
 </StackPanel>

Comment: @Arun - Move posted XAML code in comments in your answer.

Comment: @RohitVats, Move to Answer - thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the visibility to Visibilty.Collapsed  for BartenderX1X1Image and Visibility.Visible for BartenderX1X2Image.

Comment: But I don't whant to have this image on every `Image`, only one should have correct source, for the rest is `Null`